# How to filter array of objects on multiple conditions and add exception?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I currently have an array of objects that is filtered based on unique IDs and unique Names being together:

Initial input:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: "Name2"
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: null
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: "Name3"
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: "Name3"
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: null
  },
  {
    id: 9999,
    name: null
  },
  {
    id: 9999,
    name: null
  },
];
```

```
data.filter((value, index, self) => {
      return (
        self.findIndex(
          (v) =>
            v.id === value.id &&
            v.name=== value.name
        ) === index
      );
});
```

```
  [
      {
        id: 1234
        name: "Name1"
      },
      {
        id: 1234
        name: "Name2"
      },
      {
        id: 1234
        name: null
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: null
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: "Name3"
      },
      {
        id: 9999
        name: null
      },
  ]
```

However, some Ids do not have any duplicates and I want to remove all the null name associated objects EXCEPT where the id is not a duplicate and to look like the following:

```
  [
      {
        id: 1234
        name: "Name1"
      },
      {
        id: 1234
        name: "Name2"
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: "Name3"
      },
      {
        id: 9999
        name: null
      },
  ]
```

At the moment the duplicated Ids with null names still exist.

Comment: have an object which maps id with count. and when filtering use that to determine the duplciates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept the filtering part you implemented as an intermediate output. using that i got a count for each id. then using that i filtered out from the intermediate array where if the has count > 1 and has a null name i remove it.

```js
 const data = [{id: 1234,name: "Name1"},{id: 1234,name: "Name1"},{id: 1234,name: "Name2"},{id: 1234,name: null},{id: 5678,name: "Name3"},{
id: 5678,name: "Name3"},{id: 5678,name: null},{id: 9999,name: null},{id: 9999,name: null},];
  
//filtering out duplicates
let a = data.filter((value, index, self) => {
      return (
        self.findIndex(
          (v) =>
            v.id === value.id &&
            v.name=== value.name
        ) === index
      );
});
    
  //get count for ids in partially filtered 
let idcount = a.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    if(!acc[curr.id])acc[curr.id] = 0
  acc[curr.id] += 1
  return acc;
},{})

//remove the duplicate nulls
let final = a.filter((el) => {
    return !(idcount[el.id]>1 && el.name===null)
})


console.log(final)
```